# get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

Today I faced a problem. In order to display the featured image, I was using

`$image = get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); echo $image;`

Which I didn't output the image. But I know that the code is correct as I had done this before in my projects. But today may be due to some case it didn't appear. But as I switched to

`the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');`

it did give me the featured image.

So, if someone has faced this problem already, please share what might be the reason for getting such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include the post ID.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr );
```

Comment: I did add a post id too but still didn't get the result. I even tested if the id is correct, and it was fine. Is there some other reason too.

Comment: My mistake was I was adding post id as the second parameter.